# Makefile, pattern rule with sub directory only work with the first dependence

Tags: design-patterns, makefile, directory, rule

here is my problem

```
SOURCES_FUNCTIONS=cJSON.c parallelisationUtilities.c
$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o : $(SOURCE_DIR)/%.c    
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ $(IFLAGS)
```

make: ***  Aucune règle pour fabriquer la cible « parallelisationUtilities.o », nécessaire pour « build/mainFunction ». Arrêt

By placing parallelisationUtilities.c before cJSON.c in SOURCES_FUNCTIONS, i get the same error with cJSON.o. Fore sure, there are no missing files..

++
Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't show enough of the makefile: you left out the most critical part which is what target is listing the object files as prerequisites.

I'll bet you have something like this:

```
xxxx: $(BUILD_DIR)/$(SOURCES_FUNCTIONS:.c=.o)
```

That's wrong, because it only adds `$(BUILD_DIR)` to the first file.  The expansion of `$(SOURCES_FUNCTIONS:.c=.o)` gives:

```
xxxx: $(BUILD_DIR)/cJSON.o parallelisationUtilities.o
```

You need to use something like this:

```
xxxx: $(patsubst %.c,$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o,$(SOURCES_FUNCTIONS))
```

so that the `BUILD_DIR` prefixes all the files.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(BUILD_DIR)/$(EXEC_MAINFUNCTION): $(patsubst %.o,$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o,$(OBJECTS_FUNCTIONS)) $(patsubst %.o,$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o,$(OBJECTS_FUNCTIONS_NOT_TO_CLEAN)) $(patsubst %.o,$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o,$(OBJECT_MAINFUNCTION))
    $(CC) $^ -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o : $(SOURCE_DIR)/%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ $(IFLAGS)
```

Thanks a lot Mad!

Comment: Much simpler, IMO, would be `$(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR)/,$(OBJECTS_FUNCTIONS) $(OBJECTS_FUNCTIONS_NOT_TO_CLEAN) $(OBJECT_MAINFUNCTION))`